# Event receiver CancelWithError

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, properties, error-handling

I need to show an error message during in the ItemAdding event from a SP2013 event receiver.
I used this code in case of error:

```
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
properties.ErrorMessage = "My error";
```

I can see the error in the page but It shows also all the trace stack.
How can i show the more beauty sharepoint default error template. (with my error description)?
[image: ErrorPage]

Comment: Its better to do List/Field validation rather than doing it via Receiver.

Comment: I need that, I have some complex field validations (I am reading other lists)

Answer (score 2):

To see a more "beautyful" error, you could enable custom errors in web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

(Help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6171.sharepoint-2010-modify-web-config-to-display-error-details.aspx)

and then use this code:

```
properties.ErrorMessage = "Error";
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CancelWithRedirectUrl`. Then show the error message on that custom page.

```
properties.ErrorMessage = "Error";
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CanceWithRedirectUrl;
properties.RedirectUrl = url; //Pass the error message in query string
```

Create a custom page and on Page_Load read the query string and show it in a label.

http://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/create-custom-error-page-for-sharepoint-event-receiver/

Comment: isn't this depricated?